# When someone transmits their disease to you

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, verbs, sentence-structure

Please imagine there is a contagious disease like cold and your colleague who sits right next to you is affected. You notice it, but don't tell anything to him. Tomorrow morning when you wake up you immediately realize that the co-worker has transmitted his cold to you. You go to work an as usual meet him again. Does the self-made sentence below sound idiomatic and natural to you to be said:

> - Your cold was spread to me.

For me, it seems to be grammatically and idiomatically natural.

Comment: I think "Your cold has affected me" sounds OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would say

You spread your cold to me.  [he was being incautious, e.g. did not cough into his upper shirt sleeve or a tissue]

Your cold has spread to me.  [germs will be germs]

P.S.  We can also say:

I've caught your cold.

I've caught the cold that is going around.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you get/catch a cold (a disease). so,

You could say:

You gave me a cold.

You gave me your cold.

I caught your cold.

Sometimes the verb "contract" is also used.  (just for more info)

e.g.
He contracted HIV from/through her.